# pyqt4 QComboBox setEditable(True) - How to setMaxLength?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qcombobox

I have a QComboBox that is tied to database VARCHAR(45) field.

The QComboBox dropdown list provides a set of default values but it is EDIT enabled and user can enter anything in it.

I want to limit the user entry length to max of 45 chars

QComboBox does not have a setMaxLength(int) like QLineEdit does.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
self.myDropDown = QComboBox()
self.myDropDown.setEditable(True)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a combo-box is editable, its [`lineEdit`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcombobox.html#lineEdit) method will give access to its line-edit widget:

```
self.myDropDown = QComboBox()
self.myDropDown.setEditable(True)
self.myDropDown.lineEdit().setMaxLength(45)
```

Comment: Is there anything similar for QTextEdit (I'm having same problem)

Comment: @storm_to. My initial guess would be that it is probably not quite so simple. But in any case: to make it easier for others to find the answers, could you ask a new question for this, please?

Comment: asked - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479391/pyqt4-qtextedit-how-to-setmaxlength)