# pyqt4 QTextEdit - How to setMaxLength?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a multi-line QTextEdit that is tied to database VARCHAR(2048) field.

I want to limit the user entry length to max of 2048 chars

QTextEdit does not have a setMaxLength(int) method like QLineEdit does.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
self.editBox = QTextEdit()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this FAQ](https://wiki.qt.io/Technical_FAQ#How_can_I_get.2Fset_the_max_length_of_a_QTextEdit_.3F) on the Qt Wiki:

> There is no direct API to set/get a maximum length of a QTextEdit, but you can handle this yourself by connecting a slot to the [contentsChanged()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextdocument.html#contentsChanged) signal and then call [toPlainText().length()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextdocument.html#toPlainText) to find out how big it is. If it is up to the limit then you can reimplement [keyPressEvent()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#keyPressEvent) and [keyReleaseEvent()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#keyReleaseEvent) to do nothing for normal characters.

You may also be interested in [this post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/6776-Text-edit-and-maxLength) which has some code attached (hopefully it works for you):

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include "TextEdit.hpp"

TextEdit::TextEdit() : QPlainTextEdit() {
connect(this, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(myTextChanged()));
}

TextEdit::TextEdit(int maxChar) : QPlainTextEdit() {
this->maxChar = maxChar;
connect(this, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(myTextChanged()));
}

int TextEdit::getMaxChar() {
return maxChar;
}

void TextEdit::setMaxChar(int maxChar) {
this->maxChar = maxChar;
}

void TextEdit::myTextChanged() {
if (QPlainTextEdit::toPlainText().length()>maxChar) {
QPlainTextEdit::setPlainText(QPlainTextEdit::toPlainText().left(QPlainTextEdit::toPlainText().length()-1));
QPlainTextEdit::moveCursor(QTextCursor::End);
QMessageBox::information(NULL, QString::fromUtf8("Warning"),
QString::fromUtf8("Warning: no more then ") + QString::number(maxChar) + QString::fromUtf8(" characters in this field"),
QString::fromUtf8("Ok"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the slot "textChanged()":

```
txtInput = QPlainTextEdit()

QObject.connect(txtInput, SIGNAL("textChanged()"), txtInputChanged)

def txtInputChanged():
    if txtInput.toPlainText().length() > maxInputLen:
        text = txtInput.toPlainText()
        text = text[:maxInputLen]
        txtInput.setPlainText(text)

        cursor = txtInput.textCursor()
    cursor.setPosition(maxInputLen)
    txtInput.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

Another possibility is to derive from "QPlainTextEdit" and reimplement the "keyPress" event filtering keys when maximum length is reached or other keys are pressed whose input is not desired.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#keyPressEvent